# React.js Animation of 3 components ends at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 3 components with different numbers. What I want is something like this:

1. All 3 numbers should increase for 2 seconds.
2. I want this animation effect to end at the same time.
3. I don't want to use another library.

What should I consider?
here is my trial.
I would appreciate it if you could give me some points to consider.

https://jsfiddle.net/pizza_hamburger_chicken/ptav9wyg/7/

```
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const AnimationNumber = ({ number }) => {
  // ------------ useRef
  // ------------ useState
  const [numberForCount, setNumberForCount] = useState(0);
  // ------------ useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    let count = 0;
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      if (count >= number) {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        console.log(++count);
        setNumberForCount(count);
      }
    }, 0.01);
  }, []);
  // ------------ methods
  // ------------ event methods
  // ------------ api methods
  return (
    <div
      data-target={number}
    >
      <strong>
        <span>{numberForCount}</span>
      </strong>
      
    </div>
  );
};

function Example() {
  return (
    <div>
      <AnimationNumber number={700}  />
      <AnimationNumber number={100} />
      <AnimationNumber number={470}  />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render( <Example />, document.getElementById('root') );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the component's only purpose is to display this number then you could avoid state altogether and use a ref and update the span's innerText directly

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleBelle/q5bLrfpm/2/)

```js
const {useState, useRef, useEffect} = React;

const _period = 10000

const AnimationNumber = ({ number, intervalTime=10, period=_period }) => {
  const countEl = useRef(null);
  const count = useRef(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (count.current < number) {
        const amountPerRun = number * (intervalTime/period);

        count.current += amountPerRun;

        countEl.current.innerText = Math.min(number, Math.floor(count.current));

        return;
      }

      clearInterval(interval)
      console.log('done!', number);
    }, intervalTime);
    
    return  () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <strong>
        <span ref={countEl} />
      </strong>
    </div>
  );
};

function Example() {
  return (
    <div>
      <AnimationNumber number={700}  />
      <AnimationNumber number={100} />
      <AnimationNumber number={470}  />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render( <Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: with this method they all seem to end at the exact same (perceivable) time

Comment: This is the answer I'm looking for, and I'm happy with the performance as well. It is also easy to maintain. It is also good that they considered various things and explained why it is good.

Answer (score 1):

[JSfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/ahmdilloo/znhgetw4/49/)

```js
const {useState, useEffect, useCallback} = React;

const animationSpeed = 7

const useCounter = (ending, start) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const ratio = parseInt(ending/100)
  useEffect(() => {
        if (start) {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (count < ending) {
          setCount(count+ratio > ending ? ending : count+ratio)
        } else {
            clearInterval(interval)
        }
        }, animationSpeed)
        return  () => clearInterval(interval)
      }
  }, [count, start])
  return count
}

const AnimationNumber = ({ number , start}) => {
  let count = useCounter(number, start)
  return (
    <div
      data-target={number}
    >
      <strong>
        <span>{count}</span>
      </strong>
      
    </div>
  );
};

function Example() {
    const [starter, setStarter] = useState(false)
    const start = useCallback(() => {
    setStarter(true)
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={start}>Start!</button>
      <AnimationNumber number={100} start={starter} />
      <AnimationNumber number={1500} start={starter} />
      <AnimationNumber number={5000} start={starter} />
      <AnimationNumber number={590} start={starter} />
      <AnimationNumber number={1024} start={starter} />
      <AnimationNumber number={3600} start={starter} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render( <Example />, document.getElementById('root') );
```

Comment: Code seems to do nothing?

Comment: sorry! forgot to fix jsfiddle link. thanks @ColinHale please check https://jsfiddle.net/xupwema7/3/

Comment: Beautifully done.

Comment: @ahmadilloo thank you for answering my question but I don't think this is what I expected.This does not satisfy the above condition.  ```I want this animation effect to end at the same time.```

Comment: @ColinHale They do not end the movement at the same time. different from the above conditions.

Comment: @ahmadiloo For your answer to make sense, I think 100 should match the rate at which 700 increases. I think this answer will be complete until you implement the effect of slowing the increment by 100. I didn't make any changes to my conditions. I just numbered it nicely.

Comment: @horoyoio i have changed it. please check https://jsfiddle.net/ahmdilloo/znhgetw4/49/